# Remove border from the back of an overlaying text

Tags: css

**Trying to achieve:**

[image]

I am trying to pull the title on the top of border and make the border disappear for the overlaying section.

I have applied border to a div and then using negative margin on the top I have pulled the title to be on the top of the border. What I am achieving is the below attached image. But how can I cut the border for the overlaying section.

Earlier I had a similar case but that time I had plane white background so I did apply `background: white` to the title and the border looked like as if I have made a cut. But in this case there is a background image.

So, if anyone has solved such a case in CSS, that would be a great help for me.

Thanks.

**Current state:**

[image]

Comment: This look like something a simple `fieldset` and `legend` will solve

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. @AlonEitan. got this on w3schools. exactly what i expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use background for your title and drag it by using margin-top or top css properties to move the title to particular place:

HTML:

```
<br>
<div>
    <h1>Pro Care kraamzorg ook bij jou in de buurt?</h1>
  <p>Vul hieronder je postcode in en doe de postcode check!</p>
  <button>
  postcode
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

h1{
    width:300px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzxp0syf/

Comment: thanks. but as I explained in my question that, I use the exact same way as you have done. but this case I didn't need background white but a transparent background. I got the solution though using fieldset and legend.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/k46jhkw4/

The same fiddle of yours using fieldset and legend. thanks to @Alon Eitan for his solution.